# "Search Results" webpart not responding

Tags: 2013, search

I have a Search Box & Search Results web part on the same page. The Search Box web part appends a hashtag to the URL (#k=term) but the Search Results web part is not updated.

I know Search is setup correctly because I get results when I replace "#" with "?" in the URL (?k=term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is some other JavaScript on the page that is interfering with that control from updating.  Try removing all your other JS references on the page and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Search Box** and **Search Result** in a same page can work together but most importantly you have to configure it properly.

In the Search Box Web part check **"Which search results page should queries be sent to?"**
[image]

In Search Results Web Part, you have to change the query.

[image]

Click on Change Query, then choose result source. I have configured a Search Result Web part where I can search my documents
[image]

For SharePoint On-Premise check following things

- SharePoint Server Search is running
- You have created a Search Search Application and content sources are properly crawled.

Comment: hi @Atish

I believe i do have search setup correctly. I do have results showing in "search results preview".

It looks like the AJAX is not working.  Search appends #k=term to the url and nothing happens.  But when i replace the # with ? in the URL the page returns results as it should.  would you have any idea why?

thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think my last tag worked. @atish